# swift GeoPoint to CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: swift, cllocationcoordinate2d

I get coordinate from FireBase in Array [FIRGeoPoint] (now renamed GeoPoint).
But i work with my map with CLLocationCoordinate2D.

I want change struct GeoPoint. I want struct receive data in GeoPoint, and return data in CLLocationCoordinate2D.

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: You can get the latitude and longitude from the GeoPoint and create a CLLocationCoordinate2D based on that information. Have you tried that?

Comment: this works great, but one developer said that there is no need to create duplicates, and it would be more correct to change the structure.

Comment: Your question is unclear, then. You said you want to receive a GeoPoint and return a CLLocationCoordinate2D. I'm not sure what "change the structure" means in this context

Comment: what would you do in this situation? Just converted the array from GeoPoint to CLLOcationCoordinate2D?

Comment: Without any more information, yes. It seems like that's what you're asking for